# Weird text in Vim help files

Tags: vim-windows, help-system

I found this in my help files. What does it mean? Why is it there?

```
vim:tw=78:fo=tcq2:isk=!-~,^*,^\|,^\":ts=8:ft=help:norl:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a ["modeline"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline), a feature of Vim. If it encounters such a line in the first or last 2 lines of a file, Vim reads settings from it and applies them to the current buffer.

Example: Forcing a file with extension `.rdf` to be handled as file type `xml`:

```
<!--
vim: ft=xml
-->
<!-- rest of file -->
```